# How do I create an Event Listener for Cursor.lockstate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'd like to add an event listener for changes to Cursor.lockState in my unity WebGL game.

If the cursor is locked, I would like to unpause the game. If I detect the cursor has been unlocked I'd then like to pause.

Here is what I have so far

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour {

public RotateCamera rotateCamera;
public GameObject pauseMenu;
private bool paused;

void Update()
{
    if (paused)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            UnpauseGame();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
    {
        Debug.Log("CursorLockMode = Locked");
        UnpauseGame();
        return;
    }
    if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Confined)
    {
        Debug.Log("CursorLockMode = Confined");
        UnpauseGame();
        return;
    }

    if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.None && paused == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("CursorLockMode = None");
        PauseGame();
    }
}

public void PauseGame()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    Cursor.visible = true;
    paused = true;
    pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
}

public void UnpauseGame()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
    paused = false;
    pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

The problem is

- When trying to unpause the game with mouse button down the game instantly pauses itself. I believe the script detects that the cursor.lockstate is unlocked and instantly re-pauses the game.

To fix this, I think I need to create an event that listens to changes in the lock state and calls the method. Rather than the method being called every frame.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I need to create an event that listens to changes in the lock
>   state and calls the method. Rather than the method being called every
>   frame.

This is simple. Don't use the [`Cursor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.html) API directly. Wrap another class around it then use property getter and setter to implement a simple event system. Check out Unity's Events and Delegates tutorial [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events).

The wrapper `AdvanceCursor.cs`:

```
public class AdvanceCursor
{
    //Not needed but included just because Cursor has a pulbic constructor
    private Cursor cursor;

    public AdvanceCursor()
    {
        cursor = new Cursor();
    }

    public static CursorLockMode lockState
    {
        set
        {
            Cursor.lockState = value;

            //Notify Event
            if (OnLockStateChanged != null)
            {
                OnLockStateChanged(value);
            }
        }

        get { return Cursor.lockState; }
    }

    public static bool visible
    {
        set
        {
            Cursor.visible = value;

            //Notify Event
            if (OnVisibleChanged != null)
            {
                OnVisibleChanged(value);
            }
        }

        get { return Cursor.visible; }
    }

    public static void SetCursor(Texture2D texture, Vector2 hotspot, CursorMode cursorMode)
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(texture, hotspot, cursorMode);

        //Notify Event
        if (OnTextureChanged != null)
        {
            OnTextureChanged(texture, hotspot, cursorMode);
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////EVENTS//////////////////////////////////

    //Event For LockState
    public delegate void cursorLockStateAction(CursorLockMode lockMode);
    public static event cursorLockStateAction OnLockStateChanged;

    //Event For visible
    public delegate void cursorVisibleAction(bool visible);
    public static event cursorVisibleAction OnVisibleChanged;

    //Event For Texture Change
    public delegate void cursorTextureAction(Texture2D texture, Vector2 hotspot, CursorMode cursorMode);
    public static event cursorTextureAction OnTextureChanged;
}
```

**USAGE**:

Simply subscribe to the events.

```
public class CursorTest: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        AdvanceCursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        AdvanceCursor.visible = true;
        //AdvanceCursor.SetCursor(...);
    }

    //Subscribe to Events
    void OnEnable()
    {
        AdvanceCursor.OnLockStateChanged += OnCursorLockStateChanged;
        AdvanceCursor.OnVisibleChanged += OnCursorVisibleChanged;
        AdvanceCursor.OnTextureChanged += OnCursorTextureChange;
    }

    //Un-Subscribe to Events
    void OnDisable()
    {
        AdvanceCursor.OnLockStateChanged -= OnCursorLockStateChanged;
        AdvanceCursor.OnVisibleChanged -= OnCursorVisibleChanged;
        AdvanceCursor.OnTextureChanged -= OnCursorTextureChange;
    }

    void OnCursorLockStateChanged(CursorLockMode lockMode)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cursor State changed to: " + lockMode.ToString());
    }

    void OnCursorVisibleChanged(bool visible)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cursor Visibility is now: " + visible);
    }

    void OnCursorTextureChange(Texture2D texture, Vector2 hotspot, CursorMode cursorMode)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cursor Texture Changed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I need to monitor Cursor.lockState directly. The reason being is that Cursor.lockState is being modified by the browser / Unity webGL, I can not rely on it to use your suggested 'SetCursor' property. I needed to know if there is a way I can add an Event / Delegate to Cursor.lockstate.

Comment: "I can not rely on it to use your suggested 'SetCursor' property." I don't understand your comment. Question is about lockState. I added visible  and  SetCursor as a bonus. The three functions should trigger an event. What problem are you having with this solution?